# Android YUV Image format

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv, image-formats

In our application, we need to transfer video, we are using Camera class to capture the buffer and send to destination,

I have set format is YV12 as a Camera parameter to receive the buffer,

for the 500X300 buffer, we receive buffer of 230400 bytes,

i want to know , is this expected buffer size ?
I believe the size would be

Y Plane = width * height = 500X300 = 150000

U Plane = width/2 * height/2 =     =  37500

V Plane = width/2 * height/2 =     =  37500

```
                               ========
                                 225000                                     
                               ========
```

Can anyone explain me, if i need to get stride values of each component, how can i get that

Is there any way to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Android document is already explained it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12

Answer (score 3):

I can show you how you can get int rgb[] from this:

```
public int[] decodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {

        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int rgb[] = new int[width * height];
        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0)
                    r = 0;
                else if (r > 262143)
                    r = 262143;
                if (g < 0)
                    g = 0;
                else if (g > 262143)
                    g = 262143;
                if (b < 0)
                    b = 0;
                else if (b > 262143)
                    b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000)
                        | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);

            }
        }
        return rgb;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but we don't want it to be convert to RGB, we would like to pass in fact compress to a decoder, which takes data into YUV format only , only the thing is , we don't know how to calucalate stride value out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple.
chekout YUVImage class from android. You can construct an YUV Image from byte[]data coming from camera preview.
You can write like this:

```
//width and height you get it from camera properties, image width and height of camera preview
YuvImage image=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, int width, int height, null);
byte[] newData = image.getYuvData();
//or if you want int format = image.getYuvFormat();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question, but I've struggled with the same issue for a few days. So I decided to write some comments to help others.
YV12 described in the Android developer site([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12)) seems not a kind of [YV12](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-yv12/) but [IMC1](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-imc1/). The page says that both of the y-stride and the uv-stride should be aligned in 16bytes.

And also this [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int)) says that:

> For YV12, the image buffer that is received is not necessarily tightly
>   packed, as there may be padding at the end of each row of pixel data,
>   as described in YV12.

Based on the above comments, I calculated it using python command line:

```
>>> w = 500
>>> h = 300
>>> y_stride = (500 + 15) / 16 * 16.0
>>> y_stride
512.0
>>> y_size = y_stride * h
>>> y_size
153600.0
>>> uv_stride = (500 / 2 + 15) / 16 * 16.0
>>> uv_stride
256.0
>>> u_size = uv_stride * h / 2
>>> v_size = uv_stride * h / 2
>>> size = y_size + u_size + v_size
>>> size
230400.0
```